# matching large vector of string against large vector of patterns

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a very large dataframe with a column containing postal codes:

```
data <- data.frame(data = rnorm(n = 4),
                   code = c("1001", "1130", "2001", "9010"),
                   stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I also have a second large-ish dataframe with postal codes patterns mapped to a zone.

```
mapping <- data.frame(code = c("10*", "20*"),
                      zone = c("zone1", "zone2"), 
                      stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I would like to join those two tables to add the `zone` column to the `data` dataframe but the volume of the data is too large to do a "rowwise" grepl. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way to deal with large objects is `data.table`. To do joins, you need a common column in both objects. I'm using `substr` to get only the first two digits of the code column in the `data` object. Also note that I removed the "*" from `mapping` as that character is not present in `data`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)
setDT(mapping)

data[, code := substr(code, start = 1, stop = 2)]
mapping[data, on="code"]

   code  zone       data
1:   10 zone1 -1.0481912
2:   11  <NA>  1.1339476
3:   20 zone2 -0.8072921
4:   90  <NA>  1.5883562
```

**DATA**

```
data <- data.frame(data = rnorm(n = 4),
                   code = c("1001", "1130", "2001", "9010"),
                   stringsAsFactors = F)
mapping <- data.frame(code = c("10", "20"),
                      zone = c("zone1", "zone2"), 
                      stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what specific method you are using when you say "rowwise" but here is what I would do in the dplyr world.

```
  mapping <- dplyr::rename(mapping, codeString = code) # rename for joining. 

  data <- data %>%
          dplyr::mutate( codeString = paste0(substr(code, 1, 2), "*")) %>%
          dplyr::left_join(mapping, by= "codeString")
```

You should be able to join like this and avoid any rowwise operation since the patter you're looking for is easy to create.